# Ошибка (405) при отправке запроса с клиента

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, vue.js, nginx, express

Пытаюсь отправить запрос с клиента (Vue spa) который лежит в пути /var/www/(имя директории в которой лежит front часть)
(ssl установлен)
вид запроса:

```
 fetch("https://website.site", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: this.state.name,
      surname: this.state.surname,
```

переменные name и surname вводятся пользователем в форму, оттуда и берутся их ненулевые значения.
А вот серверная часть на фреймворке express, которая должна прослушивать запросы с клиента

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('i have a quest POST')
});
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('i have a quest GET')
});
const PORT = 5000

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('POST IS LISTENING')
})
```

сервер лежит в /root/server.js, запускаю его командой node server.js, но при попытке отправить запрос с клиента получаю ошибку 405 - не разрешенный метод, при попытке сменить порт сервера на 443 получаю ошибку в консоли, что порт уже занят, так как его прослушивает nginx приложение которое использует ssl сертификат, вопрос: как мне настроить сервер и клиент так, чтобы они общались на любом другом порту, но при этом сайт работал на https, пытался настроить проксирование в nginx конфиге, и устанавливал строку:

```
proxy_pass http://website.site:5000
```

перезапускал конфиг, но сайт падал с ошибкой 502.

Comment: `proxy_pass http://localhost:5000`?

Comment: На какой именно запрос вы получаете ошибку 405? Когда вы делаете fetch с постом из браузера, при некоторых обстоятельствах браузер предварительно делает запрос методом OPTIONS, а у вас на сервере его нет. Гуглить CORS и prefetch request

Comment: @nörbörnën, если я поставлю значение на localhost сайт ляжет, понятия не имею почему так происходит, проксирование я особо не трогал и не косячил с ним.

Comment: я решил проблему, указав пути к исполняемым статичным файлам непосредственно в server.js